Flutter auto_route with deeplink before authentication event
When application started,AuthCheck event always only run after deepLinkBuilder, therefore couldn't get the authentication result in AuthGuard. How to ensure AuthCheck has already completed before deeplinkBuilder read on it.
return MultiBlocProvider(
  providers: [
    BlocProvider(
      create: (_) => AuthBloc(
        authRepo: getIt(),
        bearerAuth: getIt(),
      )..add(const AuthCheck()),
    ),
    [...]
  ],
  child: BlocBuilder<AppBloc, AppState>(
    buildWhen: (previousState, currentState) {
      return previousState.language != currentState.language;
    },
    builder: (context, state) {
      return Builder(builder: (context) {
        final appRouter = AppRouter(
          navigatorKey: AppView.globalNavKey,
          guard: AuthGuard(context.read<AuthBloc>()),
        );

        return MaterialApp.router(
          routerConfig: appRouter.config(
            rebuildStackOnDeepLink: true,
            deepLinkBuilder: (link) {
            /* WHEN APP START WILL RUN HERE 
             BUT THE AUTH STATE IS ALWAYS UNAUTHENTICATED */
              if (link.path.contains('/login')) {
                return const DeepLink([LoginRoute()]);
              } else {
                return DeepLink.defaultPath;
              }
            },
          ),
           builder: (context, child) => BlocListener<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
            listener: (BuildContext context, AuthState state) {
              if (state.status == AuthStatus.authenticated) {
                appRouter.replaceAll([const HomePanelRoute()]);
              } else if (state.status == AuthStatus.unauthenticated) {
                appRouter.replaceAll([const LoginRoute()]);
              }
            },
            child: child,
          ),
        );
      });
    },
  ),
);

Bloc event
 void _onAuthCheck(
  AuthCheck event,
  Emitter<AuthState> emit,
  ) async {
    try {
     String? jwt = await _bearerAuth.getJwt();
     if (jwt != null && jwt.isNotEmpty) {
      emit(state.copyWith(status: AuthStatus.authenticated));
     } else {
      emit(state.copyWith(status: AuthStatus.unauthenticated));
     }
    } catch (ex) {
     emit(state.copyWith(status: AuthStatus.unauthenticated));
   }
}

AuthGuard
class AuthGuard extends AutoRouteGuard {
 AuthGuard(this.bloc);
 final AuthBloc bloc;
 @override
 void onNavigation(NavigationResolver resolver, StackRouter router) {
   print("authguard ${bloc.status}");
   resolver.next();
 }
}

